# What is difference between count() and limits api in salesforce?

Tags: rest-api

I try to get count of lead object. I used two apis. But both are giving different results for the same user.

```
/services/data/v41.0/limits/recordCount?sObjects=Lead
```

gives result as

```
 {
  "sObjects" : [ {
    "count" : 422,
    "name" : "Lead"
  } ]
}
```

but

```
/services/data/v41.0/query?q=SELECT COUNT() FROM Lead
```

gives result as

```
{
  "totalSize" : 423,
  "done" : true,
  "records" : [ ]
}
```

What is the difference of the above two. Which one is exact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recordCount API gives you the values that were last calculated for your org (from Storage Usage in the Setup menu). This number does not include newly created or deleted records. I believe it's updated every few hours or so. It also does not consider sharing, so this value will typically be higher than what a typical user can see (assuming a Private Organization Wide Default), but will be accurate for a particular moment in time (just not the *current* moment in time). It also cannot return values for objects that do not appear in Storage Usage. It is used to estimate how much storage you're using for a particular object. This API is *fast* because it uses cached results.

The query, on the other hand, actually performs a query to find all matching records. In your case, there were 423 records the user could see. If you added a filter, it'd show fewer records. For example, just converted leads: `SELECT COUNT() FROM Lead WHERE IsConverted = TRUE`. Unlike a normal query with fields, it only returns a totalSize attribute that gives you the exact number of records that match the query. This is useful if you wanted to answer questions like "How many leads are converted" or "How many accounts have had activity this month", without actually transferring all of those records to your client. This API is *slower* because it must actually perform a full query to determine the results.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any mention of aggregate queries in the [Force.com REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm). <strike>Aggregate queries don't return SObjects but instead return map-like [AggregateResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) objects as new values such as the `COUNT()` value need to be included.</strike> Correction: see Adrian's comment: a query that only has `COUNT()` returns an integer. Perhaps someone else can confirm that they do or do not work over this API.

The `totalSize` field is provided as part of the mechanism to be able to make a series of requests where the results are too big to transfer in one request. As your `COUNT()` query would only return one row, what it represents in this case is hard to say and AFAIK not documented.

The `recordCount` API is [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_record_count.htm?search_text=recordCount) as:

> The returned record count is approximate

so doesn't look like a good way to go either if you are looking for an exact result...

Comment: Using `count()` doesn't give you an `AggregateResult`. It gives you an `Integer` using `countQuery()`.